# Replace an img src on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace **logo-text-black** src attribute so that the svg img changes as the user scrolls. Is it possible to add this to my current script?

**img/logo-text-white.svg** // Top State

**img/logo-text-black.svg** // Scroll State

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <a href="#top"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.svg"></a>
   <a href="#top"><img class="logo-text" src="img/logo-text-white.svg">
 </a>
 </div>
</nav>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var value = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (value > 100)
   $(".navbar-default").css("background", "white"); // Scroll State
   else
  $(".navbar-default").css("background", "transparent"); // Top state
});
```

Comment: What the image/images do you want per scroll? need to clarify the logic

Comment: img/logo-text-black.svg -- on top state
img/logo-text-black2.svg -- on scroll state

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To replace image source you may use jQuery `.attr` method:

```
var initialSrc = "img/logo.svg";
var scrollSrc = "img/logo-text-black.svg";

$(window).scroll(function() {
   var value = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (value > 100)
      $(".logo").attr("src", scrollSrc);
   else
      $(".logo").attr("src", initialSrc);
});
```

This approach requires only one `<img>` with `logo` class in the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#top"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.svg"></a>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I'll keep that method in mind. Thanks

Comment: great, you saved me,,,

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact that the simple answer to the question asked is that you use the `.attr` function to change an attribute for an element when using jQuery, this is how I would go about accomplishing the task set forth in your question.

First, I would put all of this in a function (mainly to separate the variables and logic from other page scripts to prevent interference).

My next bit of advice would be to implement the background color change in two or more CSS classes. This has the benefit of simplifying the JavaScript, as well as keeping the styling part in the styling area.

Next, I like to make constant variables for my "magic words", so that if I change the word used later on I only have to change the word once in the code, instead of everywhere the word is used.

```
// cache the magic words
const DARK  = 'dark';
const LIGHT = 'light';
```

I would put the image sources into an object where the keys are the magic words associated with those sources. This allows for quick and convenient lookup later.

```
// define our different sources for easy access later
const sources = {
  light: "http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/fff/000?text=logo",
  dark:  "http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/000/fff?text=logo"
};
```

After that I would pre-load the images to prevent a visual delay the first time the source is changed.

```
// pre-load the images to prevent jank
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
  <div style="display: none!important">
    <img src="${ sources[LIGHT] }">
    <img src="${ sources[DARK] }">
  </div>
`);
```

It is important to note that performing tasks *on-scroll* can cause problems.

The main problems are:

- The effects can be blocking, which means that process heavy tasks will cause "scroll jank". This is where there is a visual inconsistency with how the page scrolls.
- It is possible for the scroll event to fire while there is already a scroll event listener executing. This may cause the two executions to interfere with each other.

Combatting these problems is easy:

- To prevent scroll-jank, wrap the handler in a `setTimeout` call. This will move the execution of the handler to the top of the stack to be executed at the next earliest convenience.
- To prevent multiple handlers from running simultaneously, define a "state" variable outside of the handler to keep track of execution state.

  This variable will be set to `true` when an event handler is executing and false when there is no event handler execution. When the handler execution begins, check the value of the state variable:

  - If it is `true`, cancel the execution of this handler call.
  - If it is `false`, set the state to true and continue.

  Just make sure that wherever you may be exiting the function, you also reset the state variable.

  ```
    // define our scroll handler
    const scroll_handler = _ => setTimeout(_ => {
      // if we are already handling a scroll event, we don't want to handle this one.
      if (scrolling) return;
      scrolling = true;

      // determine which theme should be shown based on scroll position
      const new_theme = document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100 ? DARK : LIGHT;

      // if the current theme is the theme that should be shown, cancel execution
      if (new_theme === theme) {
        scrolling = false;
        return;
      }

      // change the values
      logo.src = sources[new_theme];
      el.classList.remove(theme);
      el.classList.add(new_theme);

      // update the state variables with the current state
      theme = new_theme;
      scrolling = false;
    });
  ```

After that, just assign the event listener.

Here it is all together:

```js
function navbarSwitcher(el) {
  // cache the reference to the logo element for use later
  const logo  = el.querySelector('.logo');
  
  // cache the magic words
  const DARK  = 'dark';
  const LIGHT = 'light'

  // define our state variables
  let scrolling = false;
  let theme = LIGHT;

  // define our different sources for easy access later
  const sources = {
    light: "http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/fff/000?text=logo",
    dark:  "http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/000/fff?text=logo"
  };
  
  // pre-load the images to prevent jank
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div style="display: none!important">
      <img src="${ sources[LIGHT] }">
      <img src="${ sources[DARK] }">
    </div>
  `);

  // define our scroll handler
  const scroll_handler = _ => setTimeout(_ => {
    // if we are already handling a scroll event, we don't want to handle this one.
    if (scrolling) return;
    scrolling = true;

    // determine which theme should be shown based on scroll position
    const new_theme = document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100 ? DARK : LIGHT;

    // if the current theme is the theme that should be shown, cancel execution
    if (new_theme === theme) {
      scrolling = false;
      return;
    }

    // change the values
    logo.src = sources[new_theme];
    el.classList.remove(theme);
    el.classList.add(new_theme);

    // update the state variables with the current state
    theme = new_theme;
    scrolling = false;
  });

  // assign the event listener to the window
  window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll_handler);
}

// attach our new plugin to the element
navbarSwitcher(document.querySelector('.wrap'));
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
.wrap.light {
  background-color: white;
}
.wrap.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap light">
  <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/fff/000?text=logo">
</div>
```